# Print out xml tags from named template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have input xml such as:

```
<XML>
    <A1>50</A1>
    <A2>20</A2>
    <A3>70</A3>
    <A4>90</A4>
    <A5>5</A5>
    <A6>45</A6>
    <A7>35</A7>
    <A8>25</A8>
    <A9>80</A9>
</XML>
```

And XSLT rule to work with it:

```
<xsl:template name="summfunc">
    <xsl:param name="summ"/>
    <xsl:param name="summands"/>
    <xsl:param name="output-text"/>
    <xsl:param name="output-node"/>
    <xsl:if test="format-number($summ, '#.##') !=format-number(sum($summands), '#.##')">
        <ERROR>
            <CODE>30</CODE>
            <TEXT><xsl:value-of select="$output-text"/></TEXT>
            <PROBLEMNODE>
                <xsl:value-of select="$output-node"/>
            </PROBLEMNODE>
        </ERROR>                    
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="/XML">

<xsl:variable name="tests">
    <xsl:call-template name="summfunc">
        <xsl:with-param name="summ" select="//A3"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="summands" select="//A1 | //A2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="output-text">abrakadabra</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="output-node" select="//A3"/>  
    </xsl:call-template>    
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:variable>     

<xsl:value-of select="$tests"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Summary I want to print:

```
        <ERROR>
            <CODE>30</CODE>
            <TEXT>some text</TEXT>
            <PROBLEMNODE>
                some text, containing node
            </PROBLEMNODE>
        </ERROR>
```

As many times, as template "summfunc" had errors. That is why I just print $tests as it is, if there were no errors, it would be empty (but maybe that is not good solution).

But it don't prints tags! I receive "30some text"  as text if there were errors, it don't print tags. When I try to put tags to xsl:text, it don't work, even if I use " or '.

How to print it right way? It perfectly prints tags if I put them between value-of select="$tests" and /xsl:template, but somehow it don't print tags if they are in named template. How to solve it?

Comment: It seems to me your XSLT could have some rework. Maybe it would be better to ask a question and provide the complete input XML. The and the expected output XML as well some documentation of the logic between your input and output.

Comment: I afraid there is no logic between many similar checks (one tag is sum of couple of other tags). And each such check have to output it's own message, without any logical connection to others. So, I have to set manually sum, summands and output text for each such check, as done above.
All I need - is to print small xmls about errors if any check fails. And I can't, because it don't allows printing XML tags from named templates, by some not-understandable reason.

Comment: I even tried to print tags using &gt; and &lt; instead of "<>", it still don't works. By some magic if there exists "<xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>" then it will print all values inside all tags in input xml: 50 20 81 90 5 45 35 25 80 (third(70) was changed (to 81) to see error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "print tags", use **xsl:copy-of** instead of **xsl:value-of**

So, all you need to do is this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$tests"/>
```

**xsl:value-of** is for outputting the text values of items.

Comment: @Arkady The **simple** solution would be to remove the variable and write the results of the called template directly to the output. -- Note that you should have a root element wrapping these, as there can be several of them. -- Note also that formatting the sums before comparing them is entirely redundant.

Comment: If I don't format sums before comparing, summing become wrong. It adds 0.00000001 to sum (I wonder where it take it), so comparation fails. That is why I added formatting...